# Randomly changing letters in list of string based on probability

Tags: python, string, list, replace, probability

Given the following

`data = ['AAACGGGATT\n','CTGTGTCAGT\n','AATCTCTACT\n']`

For every letter in a string not including (\n), if its probability is greater than 5 (i.e. there is a 50% chance for a change), I'd like to replace the letter with a randomly selected letter from options (A,G,T,C), with the caveat that the replacement cannot be the same as original.

This is what I'm attempted thus far:

```
import random

def Applyerrors(string, string_length, probability):
    i=0
    while i < string_length:
        i = i + 1
        p = i/string_length
        if p > probability:
            new_var = string[i]
            options = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C'] 
            [item.replace(new_var, '') for item in options]
            replacer = random.choice(options)
            [res.replace(new_var, replacer) for res in string]
        else:
            pass
        
# Testing
data_updated = [Applyerrors(unit, 10, 0.5) for unit in data]
data_updated
```

The result from this:

```
[None, None, None]
```

In addition to not getting the desired result, my probability doesn't make sense as I'm hoping to achieve 50% overall change in the data_updated file.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: `Applyerrors()` does not have a `return` statement.  Why would you expect it to return anything?

Comment: Can you please explain the whole probability thing? What is the point of `i/string_length`? Also, there is no need to explicitly pass in the length of the string. Just call `len(string)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

There are a few problems that I can see right away.

1. You are not returning anything in `Applyerros`, so the value in the loop `[Applyerrors(unit, 10, 0.5) for unit in data]` will be `None` every time.
2. When you do `[res.replace(new_var, replacer) for res in string]` you are replacing every instance of a letter with another, so there would be a change 50% of the time, but the change would cover more than 50% of the data.
3. When you do `[item.replace(new_var, '') for item in options]` you give `replacer` a chance to choose the empty string (`''`) as an option to replace a value, rather than removing the same value from the list of options.
4. You increment i before using it, so it will always skip the first character of the string.
5. You don't do a check to avoid changing the newline character.

---

### The Solution

```py
def Applyerrors(string, string_length, probability):
    i = 0
    while i < string_length:
        if string[i] == "\n":
            continue
        p = i/string_length
        if p > probability:
            new_var = string[i]
            options = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C'] 
            options.remove(new_var)
            replacer = random.choice(options)
            string = string[:i] + replacer + string[i+1:]
            
        i = i + 1
    return string
```

1. `return string` When `Applyerrors` is done, it returns the edited string at the end.
2. `string = string[:i] + replacer + string[i+1:]` replaces just the character at index `i`. (`string[:i]` is everything from 0 up to, but not including i. `string[i:]` is everything from i to the end of the string`)
3. `options.remove(new_var)` removes the value from the list entirely rather than replacing it with an empty string.
4. `i = i+1` was moved to the end of the loop to allow for i to be 0 for an iteration to include the first value.
5. `if string[i] == "\n"` Added a check to skip any newline characters. (`continue` skip the rest of the current iteration of the loop)

---

### The Solution Continued

While none of the following changes are necessary, I have recreated the function below to show some best practices.

```py
def apply_errors(data, prob):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        options = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C']
        current = data[i]
        if current not in options or random.random() > prob:
            continue
        options.remove(current)
        data = data[:i] + random.choice(options) + data[i+1:]
    return data
```

- `for i in range(len(data))` removes the need for inputting the length of the string.
- `if current not in options or random.random() > prob`

  - `current not in options` checks if the value is not present in options (so now it will ignore `\n` and anything else that shouldn't be changed)
  - `random.random() > prob` will now breakout of the iteration if the probability is greater than a random number (`random.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1). This would make the input probability represent the chance that a value **is** changed. The way you have it currently, the input probability would be the probability that a value is **not** changed.
- `random.random() > prob` makes it so that any value has the same probability of changing. The old version guarantees that the last 50% (when probability = 0.5) of the string will change.
- rename `string` to `data`. Its not great to have a variable named the same as a data type (despite strings being represented as `str` in python).
- The new function header `apply_errors` uses snake case, which is the preferred method of naming variables and functions in python.

Comment: Thank you for this well-thought-out answer. I'm incredibly appreciative. I'm understanding strings are read-only and the empty strings are still strings, and thus will exist. I'd love to tip you, do you have "buy me a coffee site"?

Comment: @Zelkins Minor correction to your last bullet point: `apply_errors` is *snake case*, not camel case (`applyErrors` or `ApplyErrors` would be camel case).

Comment: @simon yep that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. It’s been fixed

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution. It doesn't use string length or track the iteration count, as each character is appended to a new list which is transformed to a `str` with `"".join(new_string)`. It preserves newlines characters.

```py
import random

def apply_errors(string, probability):
    new_string = []
    for nucleobase in string:
        if nucleobase != "\n" and probability > random.random():
            nucleobase = random.choice("ACGT".replace(nucleobase, ""))
        
        new_string.append(nucleobase)
    
    return "".join(new_string)
```